# PDO: Multi. Row and Column - How to loop through array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

This is my array:

[image]

When I used mysqli_query in a *different* script, this style worked:

```
while ($printTest = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo $printTest['id'] . "<br />"; 
    echo $printTest['questions'] . "<br />";
    echo $printTest['answers'] . "<br />";
}
```

I can't figure out how to do the same thing with a PDO created array. With PDO, I can use foreach, like this:

```
foreach ($queryRows as $test=>questions){
    echo $test; 
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't give me access to `id` and `answers` in the same loop - which is important to me.

This is how I'm getting my PDO-generated array, currently:

```
$queryRows = $this->dbh->query("SELECT id, questions, answers FROM qarows WHERE usr = '$this->username'");
$queryRows = $queryRows->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

How do I access all 3 columns of my array, in a loop?

Comment: what is `echo $test;` outputting on each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still the same fetch rows from db. Its still the same multi dimensional structure:

```
$select = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT id, questions, answers FROM qarows WHERE usr = :usr');
$select->bindParam(':usr', $this->username);
$select->execute();
$queryRows = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($queryRows as $questions){
    echo $questions['id'] . '<br/>'; 
}
```

Or the look a like mysqli:

```
$select = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT id, questions, answers FROM qarows WHERE usr = :usr');
$select->bindParam(':usr', $this->username);
$select->execute();

while($printTest = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $printTest['id'] . "<br />"; 
    echo $printTest['questions'] . "<br />";
    echo $printTest['answers'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I thought I had already tried what you said in the first code. Maybe I typed it wrong.. Thank you, Ghost.